# Calculate height of uilabel Fail after passing into onther viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, uilabel, parameter-passing

so i have problems to calculate UIlabel text height after passing it to another window/viewcontrollers

heres my code to passing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NetraDealsObject *dataObject=[self.deals_data_json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    detailViewController = [[MJDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
    detailViewController.NetraPopupPrice.text=dataObject.formatted;

}
```

for example the text==123;

and here the detailviewController

```
-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self=[super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self){

        NetraPopupPrice=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        NetraPopupPrice.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.31 green:0.733 blue:0 alpha:1]; /*#4fbb00*/
        NetraPopupPrice.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        NetraPopupPrice.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        NetraPopupPrice.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18];
        [NetraPopupPrice.layer setCornerRadius:3];


        NetraPopupProvider=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135.0f, 55, 80, 16)];
        NetraPopupProvider.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        NetraPopupProvider.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.769 green:0.776 blue:0.788 alpha:1];
        NetraPopupProvider.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];

        //separator
        NetraPopupSeparator=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215,55.0f, 80, 16)];
        NetraPopupSeparator.text=@"-",
        NetraPopupSeparator.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        NetraPopupSeparator.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.769 green:0.776 blue:0.788 alpha:1];
        NetraPopupSeparator.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];

        //
        //separator
        NetraPopupLocation=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225,  55.0f, 70, 16)];
        NetraPopupLocation.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        NetraPopupLocation.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.769 green:0.776 blue:0.788 alpha:1];
        NetraPopupLocation.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13];

        NetraPopupHeadline=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        NetraPopupHeadline.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.227 green:0.243 blue:0.247 alpha:1];
        NetraPopupHeadline.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        NetraPopupHeadline.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        NetraPopupHeadline.numberOfLines=0;
        NetraPopupHeadline.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13];



    }
    [[self view] addSubview:NetraPopupPrice];

    [[self view] addSubview:NetraPopupProvider];
    [[self view] addSubview:NetraPopupSeparator];
    [[self view] addSubview:NetraPopupLocation];
    [[self view] addSubview:NetraPopupHeadline];
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
    CGSize NetraLabelForPriceWidth = [[NetraPopupPrice text] sizeWithFont:[NetraPopupPrice font]];
    CGFloat NetraLabelForPriceW = NetraLabelForPriceWidth.width;

    NSLog(@"Width=%f",NetraLabelForPriceW);
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

}
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

and the result when log it

```
NSLog(@"Width=%f",NetraLabelForPriceW);
```

is:

```
[9858:19d03] Width=0.000000
```

it should be calculate right? anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging the address of your **`NetraPopupPrice` and its text** in viewDidLoad. Also try "adding to Subview" inside the `if(self)` block of initWithNibName.

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
 NSLog(@"NetraText %@",NetraPopupPrice.text);

}

[10811:19d03] NetraText (null)

why its return null? but show in app

Comment: how to adding subview? is that like  [[self view] addSubview:NetraPopupProvider];

Comment: Yes, do that inside the if(self) block.

Comment: Add subviews inside the if block, Not outside it. (Not sure, but you can try).

Comment: I think it might help to analyze your code or tweak with a copy of it. Use some NSLog's (like I had mentioned in the answer) at times to get you going in the right direction. Helps in learning.

Comment: yup.. i know man.. so when deadlock on this method.. i do tweak my detail view controller from mainviewcontroller.. and guess. it works

Answer (score 0):

You are currently displaying first the view, before you set the text.  Thus, when `viewDidLoad` is called, `[NetraPopupPrice text]` is still `nil`, resulting in your `NetraLabelForPriceW` to become `0`.

Instead, you should place

```
detailViewController.NetraPopupPrice.text=dataObject.formatted;
```

before

```
[self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideBottomBottom];
```

so that when your detail view controller's `viewDidLoad` is called, `[NetraPopupPrice text]` would already contain the correct string.

Comment: still return to [10418:19d03] Width=0.000000 i've put the code like your suggestion